# For a motion to be periodic must it have same amplitude over all time interval? Can a periodic motion have changing amplitude?

Tags: kinematics, definition

For a motion to be periodic must it have same amplitude over all time interval? Can a periodic motion have changing amplitude?

Answer (score 1):

The answer straightaway is that **changing amplitude is not a form of periodic motion**. For details read further.

A function $f(t)$ is said to be periodic if there exists some real number $T$ such that for all $t$,
$$f(t+T)=f(t)$$
Amplitude $A$ of such a function is defined to be: $$A=\text{max}[f(t)]-\text{min}[f(t)]$$

This implies that if the amplitude does not remain constant then the function can no longer be periodic. As the maximum/minimum of the function changes, it will never reach the old maximum/minimum. Thus violating the definition as there exist no single $T$ for which function goes back to original value.

Comment: it means that a periodic motion can not have changing amplitude. A periodic motion will always stays the same. If a motion has same frequency but changing amplitude over time period T than it will not be regarded as periodic

Comment: It’s not periodic. It is still oscillatory though.

Comment: so it means that in real life the motion of pendulum is not periodic

Comment: That is correct. Because it in real life, the swinging of the pendulum eventually stops.

Comment: sir i have read at some place that in a periodic motion the amplitude can change but the time period should remain same so it means that information is wrong

Comment: Yeah that is incorrect. The motion could still be oscillatory without being periodic. The case of a decaying pendulum is an example of that.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish is correct. I have deleted my answer.